# The logic about onDraw of ImageView

Tags: android

The class MyImageView extended ImageView, In method onDraw(), I have following code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.setImageBitmap(someBitmap);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Although the code works, I am wonder why onDraw has not benn called infinitely, since setImageBitmap will call onDraw -->right or not? I am still want to know is there performance issue for above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setImageBitmap() will call invalidate() which will in turn call onDraw() later on. What you are doing is a really bad idea :)

Comment: Yes, it is a bad idea. actually, Although the UI shows correctly. I can see the method onDraw() has been called infinitely by Log information.